# Get value from property that's value is xml

Tags: javascript

I have a property that's contain :   `<date xmlns="http://test.com/ds">20200222</date>.`

And i want to get the value '20200222' how can i do it ?   knowing that if it's empty i get `<date xmlns="http://test.com/ds"/>`
please advise .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator coupled with `querySelector` and get the text using `innerHTML`

```js
document.querySelector('date').innerHTML==''?console.log(document.querySelector('date')):console.log(document.querySelector('date').innerHTML)
```

```html
<date xmlns="http://test.com/ds">20200222</date>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `<date xmlns="http://test.com/ds">20200222</date>` is a string, you can use slice.

```
var str = '<date xmlns="http://test.com/ds">20200222</date>';
var value = str.slice(str.indexOf('>')+1, str.indexOf('</date>');
console.log(value); //prints "20200222"
```

When there is no date, same method returns blank string:

```
var str = '<date xmlns="http://test.com/ds"/>';
var value = str.slice(str.indexOf('>')+1, str.indexOf('</date>');
console.log(value); //prints ""
```